# Delimited list web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a user interface similar to the following. Basically, given a delimited text, it will be able to split the text and group each element separately.

*Gmail Example:*

[image: Stack Over Flow]

*Stack Over Flow Example:*

[image: Gmail]

What is this concept called?

Are there any JavaScript libraries that perform this?

Comment: search in google `jquery tag input plugin`.

Comment: Probably best known as tags/tagging

Answer (score 1):

You can use a jQuery library called jQuery Tags Input

[Demo](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/example.html) | [Github](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input)

Answer (score 1):

That's called **Tagging** in simplest terms, and yes, there's javascript library for it called `TaggingJS`, which you can find the github repository of it, in the below link;

[TaggingJS](https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS)

You can also look at my jsfiddle, which is a mini version of it,

[Tag](http://jsfiddle.net/Wky2Z/11/)